# Unknown pixel format error SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, pixelformat

I've been working on a project in SDL, and I've narrowed a problem to a surface being NULL.
The surface is initialized like so:

```
boardSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 780, 480, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (boardSurface == NULL)
    { 
        std::cout << "SURFACE ERROR " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
```

It prints "SURFACE ERROR Unknown pixel format".
I assume its referring to the last four arguments in the SDL_CreateRGBSurface function, but I don't know what could be causing. Google has been.. unhelpful. And so I turn to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter `depth` can't be NULL. Try changing it to 32.

The function is declared as:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_CreateRGBSurface(Uint32 flags,
                                  int    width,
                                  int    height,
                                  int    depth,
                                  Uint32 Rmask,
                                  Uint32 Gmask,
                                  Uint32 Bmask,
                                  Uint32 Amask)
```

See the SDL 2.0 documentation: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface

Answer (score 0):

From http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_CreateRGBSurface

The prototype of `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` is:

```
SDL_Surface *SDL_CreateRGBSurface(Uint32 flags, int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel, 
                                  Uint32 Rmask, Uint32 Gmask, Uint32 Bmask, Uint32 Amask);
```

You are passing `NULL` for the `bitsPerPixel` argument. That should be a number like 8, 24 or 32 instead, depending on what you are after.

In any case, you can use `SDL_GetError()` to get the exact error message which will be more helpful:

```
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, width, height, 32,
                               rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
if(surface == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateRGBSurface failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
}
```